# Why does cygwin terminal only show .lnk on Desktop, no folders?

Tags: cygwin

I tried to use cygwin bash as my main terminal. 
ls, mkdir, rm commands run ok.

But on my desktop I want to go in folders, but it shows no folders! Only some lnk labels to programs.

[image: k]

Comment: It seems you have no folders on the Desktop, only link to programs.

Comment: @matzeri,  i got bunch of folders here - http://prntscr.com/kuxy85

Comment: there is also the `users\Public\Desktop` and some others. Several `Desktop` folders are merged to provide the visual one.